# Logic about handling dates in better way

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am going to ask a very basic question about handling dates but for me it was always a problem to handle it. My problem is that sometimes we have an option to show a `DatePicker`. I mostly use *jQueryUI* or *KendoUI*. That is okay but to bind I mostly use `DateTime` property with model:

Model:

```
public DateTime? DateOfService { get; set; }
```

In view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfService, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
<script>
  $("#DateOfService").datepicker();
</script>
```

Suppose in database I have a field that is nullable and it is of `DateTime` data type.
Now, the user can leave the field empty so I have taken a nullable type property in model. Assume user selects a date and hit save. When The user comes to edit the page, the `datePicker` shows also the time like "2/18/2014 12:00:00 AM".

If I use string time of property in the model, then It always becomes an overhead to convert into `DateTime` while saving and then to string type while retrieving. Moreover, Validation also becomes hectic.

Can you please guide me what is the best method I can use in MVC to handle fields of web page that are dates?

Comment: The KendoUI DatePicker has the ability to format the `DateTime` value. I always format the date using [these available formats](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting).

Comment: but you are going particular for kendo. Please suggest something universal .

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Both controls provide date formating. For Kendo see [this link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting) and for JQueryUI see [this one](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `DescriptionAttribute`?

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DateOfService { get; set; }
```

This should display the date in a format this is suitable.

Comment: Can you please also tell me that having DateTime property in model for DatePicker is better or we can use string Type property. Which is better?

Comment: @Sweetie The attribute needs to be used in conjunction with `EditorFor` call.

Comment: @Kami, that's kind of restricting. It would work, but the instantiation of the `DatePicker` must be done in `document.ready`. This rules out some "easy" scenarios like using Kendo UI for MVC wrappers. In this particular situation, a workaround would be to tell the editor to use a template for `DateTime` properties, in which the component is instantiated with the provided value.